# ifstream can't open in Qt 5.5.0 windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ifstream

Two years ago, I developed a application on ubuntu with Qt 5.0.2. I used this code to open my file and it works perfectly. I tried on windows too and it works.

```
QString file = inAlgorithm->getFile().absoluteFilePath();
stream.open(file.toStdString());
if(!stream.fail())
{
 ...
}
```

Now on Qt 5.5.0 in windows, the same code doesn't work. If I select a file in the disk D the stream fail. But if I select a file in the disk C the application crashs and I obtain this message: an unhandled win32 exception occurred in my_program.exe [3332]. I try to run with Qt 5.0.2 but I obtain the same problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Start by running in a debugger to actually catch and locate the crash in your code.

Comment: When I open visual studio I obtain this: Unhandled exception at 0x00403491 in my_program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

Comment: Build a debug version of your program, and when you *run in the debugger* it will stop at the location of the crash, and you can find out what null-pointer you are dereferencing (yes, that kind of message is what you typically get when dereferencing a null pointer)..

Comment: The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system. Signal name: SIGSEGV. Signal meaning: Segmentation fault

Comment: Again, *run in a debugger*! It will catch the crash and show you the location in your code where the crash happens. And are you running on two different platforms? Windows doesn't have "segmentation faults".

Comment: I developed on ubuntu and now I try on windows so I just run on windows. I think I understand what you want. It blocks in hashtable.h (not one of my file) on line size_type
_M_bucket_index(const key_type& __k, __hash_code __c) const
{ return __hash_code_base::_M_bucket_index(__k, __c, _M_bucket_count); }

Comment: When you catch the crash in a debugger, you can walk up the call-stack. Do that until you reach your code.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem. The problem doesn't come from the code but from the option shadow build in qt creator. I desactive it and now it works. I don't know why. The second problem: when I open the file from the disk C it works but not from my disk D. It's because I have a folder with an accent (I'm french).